# npm install behavior after clear cache vs folder delete

Tags: node.js, caching, npm

I am trying to understand how `npm` work on cache clean and installation. Whenever I have to get latest latest version I try to do:

```
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install
```

But it fails to pickup latest dependencies so I always have to do delete old dependent project folder from node_module folder and do `npm install`

So I want to understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm cache clean` only purges the global cache `npm` uses to avoid re-downloading the same packages. `npm install` does nothing if the installed package versions match the versions in `package.json`.

Maybe the command you're looking for is [`npm update`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update)?